# Configuring rDNS and PTR Record

Tags: reverse-dns, ptr-record

I know that here was a few questions about it, but they didn't answer my question.

Here is my issue.

I have a mailserver on my dedicated server with full access. In robots I wrote down these lines of code:

```
mail.domain.com          IN A       11.22.333.444
444.333.22.11.in-addr.arpa       IN PTR     mail.domain.com.
```

But for  `dig -x 11.22.333.444` it returns:

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9910
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;444.333.22.11.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
444.333.22.11.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN    PTR     444.333.22.11.in-addr.arpa.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
333.22.11.in-addr.arpa. 18516   IN      NS      ns.second-ns.com.
333.22.11.in-addr.arpa. 18516   IN      NS      ns3.second-ns.de.
333.22.11.in-addr.arpa. 18516   IN      NS      ns1.your-server.de.

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 213.133.100.100#53(213.133.100.100)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 19 09:30:35 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 148
```

I was applying the rules which were written in [ietf](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2317.txt), but still cannot setup rdns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I edited it. It is dedicated server. @JennyD

Comment: That doesn't make any difference to the issue.

Comment: Your post suggests that you have both an A record and a PTR record in the same zone file? Thus loaded under the same zone within BIND? As I understand DNS, this is completely incorrect (I am presuming you are using BIND, as you've not specifically stated which DNS daemon you are using).

Comment: A and PTR are normally delegated at the higher levels by completely independent zones/dns tree structures. The A record is probably fine. For the PTR record, take the 3 most significant octets of your IP address and run: dig -t ns 333.22.11.in-addr.arpa. - this should return some name servers. These are the name servers the PTR records should be setup on. Run: dig -t ns 22.11.in-addr.arpa. if the previous dig command returned no NS records.

Comment: do you mean all the setup, including DNS servers,is a lab? this would change the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @parkamark. That helped. Problem was with setting up of PTR on wrong name servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exemple in a lab setup
DNS domain name : domain.com
server IP address : 11.22.33.44

you need :

- a standard (I.E. forward) DNS zone for "domain.com."
- a reverse DNS zone for: 33.22.11.in-addr.arpa.

In the forward zone you put the MX record and the A record (you should also set spf)

```
domain.com. IN MX 10 mail.domain.com.
mail.domain.com. IN A 11.22.33.44
```

In the reverse DNS zone you put the reverse record

```
44 IN PTR mail.domain.com.
```

Outside a lab, usually you don't control the reverse DNS zone, it may be your ISP that control it, so you have to ask the ISP (or whoever control it) to set the reverse record for your server public IP.

Comment: Thanks, @JFL. Even though it was not lab, but I also forgot to put MX record.